# Простейший калькулятор на JavaScript. Не могу понять почему не работает код, подскажите мне, безграмотному :)

Tags: javascript, html, select, switch

```js
    <script>
        function a() {
           var a1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('a1').value);
           var b1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('b1').value);
            if (isNaN(a1)==true) a1=0;
            if (isNaN(b1) == true) b1 = 0;
            var ddl = document.getElementById('oper');
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            
            switch (selectedValue) {
                case '+':
                    {
                        var total = a1 + b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '-':
                    {
                        var total = a1 - b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '*':
                    {
                        var total = a1 * b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '/':
                    {
                        var total = a1 / b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="a1" value="10" size="6"/>
            <select size="1" name="oper" style="width:150px;">
                <option>Выберите действие</option>
                <option value="+">+</option>
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="b1" value="2" size="6"/>
            <input type="button" value="Расчитать" onclick="a()" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>        
        <p> Ответ =</p><p>
            <textarea сols="20" rows="1" id="count" ></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Первая ошибка: вы в коде пытаетесь получить document.getElementById('oper'), но у вашего select не id такой, а name, если вы хотите получать элементы именно по имени то используйте getElementsByName, но в данном случае в вашем html поменяйте name на id

2). в уже в .js не используйте тег 'script' а подключайте его в вашем html, как внешний скрипт, либо пишете в том же html файле заключив ваш js код в тег 'script', прикладываю ниже ваш код с учетом этих правок:

```js
        function a() {
           var a1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('a1').value);
           var b1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('b1').value);
            if (isNaN(a1)==true) a1=0;
            if (isNaN(b1) == true) b1 = 0;
            var ddl = document.getElementById('oper');
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            
            switch (selectedValue) {
                case '+':
                    {
                        var total = a1 + b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '-':
                    {
                        var total = a1 - b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '*':
                    {
                        var total = a1 * b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
                case '/':
                    {
                        var total = a1 / b1;
                        var el = document.getElementById('count');
                        el.textContent = total;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
 
            <input type="text" id="a1" value="10" size="6"/>
            <select size="1" id="oper" style="width:150px;">
                <option>Выберите действие</option>
                <option value="+">+</option>
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="b1" value="2" size="6"/>
            <input type="button" value="Расчитать" onclick="a()" />
  
    </div>
    <div>        
        <p> Ответ =</p><p>
            <textarea сols="20" rows="1" id="count" ></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не заметил, большое спасибо, работает)